# Does installing next QGIS 'build' require uninstalling previous version?

Tags: qgis, installation, mac

I am using a Mac OS-10.10.5 ("Yosemite") and have been running QGIS 2.10 "Pisa". Several people have reported issues about processing rasters (http://hub.qgis.org/issues/13162), so I am chomping at the bit to install QGIS 2.12 (supposed to be coming out soon!).

Before I install the new version (QGIS 2.12), do I need to uninstall the old 2.10 version?

Answer (score 1):

No, rename the 2.10 version as QGIS_2.10.app and install the new version (as QGIS.app). If you want a new version, you can also use the [Nightly Mac Build of QGIS from 'master' Branch](http://qgis.dakotacarto.com/) (one version per day, currently QGIS 2.13 version)

Comment: With the Kyngchaos QGIS 2.8 LTR there is a Readme that includes the following: "If you rename an installed QGIS before installing a newer major version (ie 2.8->2.10), be aware that they use the same preferences and plugins, and there may plugin or preference incompatibilities. Especially with builtin plugins that may store the path to a support executable in the QGIS app package, even if it’s the default and you don’t explicitly set it - you could end up with one QGIS app executing an incompatible plugin program in another QGIS app."

Comment: That is the theory if you are not familiar with QGIS. I have three versions  that are running  (2.8, 2.10, dev) without problems. The only thing is that some plugins (one or two) don't work in all versions

Comment: I appreciate the help. I still don't know what the best thing is to do. It sounds like the Kyngchaos warning applies, and I should not rename the older version. I don't see any point in keeping the 2.10 version once the 2.12 is installed, so -- I guess I'll (try to) delete the 2.10 version. Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Do as you wish but it is not a real problem (2.10 + 2.12 + dev version). The 2.12 version of KyngChaos  is not yet available.